# Neatest way to build a data frame from a list of lists in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list of sub-lists that I wish to convert to a data frame (specifically as a tibble); for example:

```
myList <- list(
        list(var1=1,var2=2,var3=3,var4=4,var5=5,var6=6),
        list(var1=4,var2=5,var3=6,var4=7,var5=8,var6=9),
        list(var1=7,var2=8,var3=9,var4=1,var5=2,var6=3)
)
```

Using the following code, I can extract chosen variables to a tibble data frame

```
myDF <- tbl_df(cbind(
  var1 = lapply(myList, '[[', "var1"),
  var2 = lapply(myList, '[[', "var2"),
  var5 = lapply(myList, '[[', "var5"),
  var6 = lapply(myList, '[[', "var6")
))
```

But it is quite verbose.  Is there a more succinct way (perhaps using a purrr map function) that can pull chosen sub-elements out of each list and populate them into a row?

Further, if the sub-lists contain lists themselves, how best to extract elements of those lists; e.g:

```
 myList <- list(
        list(var1=1,var2=2,var3=3,list4=list(varA="a",varB="b")),
        list(var1=4,var2=5,var3=6,list4=list(varA="c",varB="d")),
        list(var1=7,var2=8,var3=9,list4=list(varA="e",varB="f"))
)
```

How could I get something like the following to work:

```
myDF <- tbl_df(cbind(
  var1 = lapply(myList, '[[', "var1"),
  var2 = lapply(myList, '[[', "var2"),
  var4 = lapply(myList, '[[', "list4$varA")
))
```

Where I want to extract a specific element from list 4, but using $ notation to drill down to the next level does not work?

Answer (score 11):

Since data frames are just lists, if your list isnt nested more than once.

```
library(tidyverse)
myList %>%
  map(as.data.frame) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  select(var1, var2, var5, var6)

#    var1 var2 var5 var6
# 1    1    2    5    6
# 2    4    5    8    9
# 3    7    8    2    3
```

Or even the following, `bind_rows()` actually works on a list of lists.

```
myList %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  select(var1, var2, var5, var6)

#    var1  var2  var5  var6
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  1.00  2.00  5.00  6.00
# 2  4.00  5.00  8.00  9.00
# 3  7.00  8.00  2.00  3.00
```

However sometimes it may be the case where each list element has only some common elements and you want to select only those specifically

```
myList %>%
  map(as.data.frame) %>%
  map(~ select(.x, var1, var2, var5, var6)) %>%
  bind_rows()

#    var1 var2 var5 var6
# 1    1    2    5    6
# 2    4    5    8    9
# 3    7    8    2    3
```

For cases where the lists are nested more than once investigate using `flatten()` from `purrr`

```
myList2 <- list(
  list(var1=1,var2=2,var3=3,list4=list(varA="a",varB="b")),
  list(var1=4,var2=5,var3=6,list4=list(varA="c",varB="d")),
  list(var1=7,var2=8,var3=9,list4=list(varA="e",varB="f"))
)  

myList2 %>%
  map(flatten) %>%
  bind_rows()

#   var1  var2  var3 varA  varB 
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
# 1  1.00  2.00  3.00 a     b    
# 2  4.00  5.00  6.00 c     d    
# 3  7.00  8.00  9.00 e     f
```

and apply `select()` as desired, the names will be the names of the respective elements. Be very careful with duplicate names in different elements as it will only take one.

There may be situations where the `enframe()` function from `tibble` is also useful.

Comment: Okay; I probably should have clarified but my list does contain some nested lists (which I want to ignore and just select some of the specific non nested variables).  So a solution that automatically flattens the list into a dataframe first is going to fail in that scenario.  What I am looking for is somewhere between a SQL Select and a "With Mylist" type method (harking back to my VBA / VB6 days of 20 years ago) so that I can pull out some (but not all) of the variables without having to explicitly reference mylist each time.

Comment: @BrisbanePom Are you sure it won't work.... provide a better example otherwise I've pretty extensively covered scenarios.

Comment: Hi @zacdav - difficult to recreate as the real world example I am applying this to is a more complex list which uses commercially sensitive data - but when I apply the "flatten method I get the following error:   Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : incompatible sizes (1 != 4).  Ultimately I am using this to pull data out of lists derived from JSON, so ideally I would like to select the elements first, and drop the ones I don't want, before converting to a data frame, to avoid cases where flattening fails due to the nesting levels in the list.

Comment: I absolutely can't help you unless you reconstruct an example, I just don't have the time to go and try and reconstruct something based on a loose description. Modify the data, its the structure that matters.

Answer (score 1):

For the first case, a possible base-R solution:

```
> data.frame(do.call(rbind, myList))[c("var1", "var2", "var5", "var5")]
var1 var2 var5 var6
1    1    2    5    6
2    4    5    8    9
3    7    8    2    3
```

Comment: I don't think this would quite achieve the results I need; note that not all elements of the list are selected.  E.g. Var3 is present in the list but should be ignored.  What I am after is something like a Select statement but I don't want to have to reference the list explicitly each time.